# Static Array and Spinner issues

Tags: android, android-layout

```
public String[] mArrayList = {" title", "sex", "name", "sex","fff","eee","iii"};            

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    this,**mArrayList**,R.layout.sq,

    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to add value to the spinner using mArrayList array.but ERROR display as below.

> The method createFromResource(Context, int, int) in the type
>   ArrayAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (sq, String[], int,
>   int).

What am I doing wrong?

How can I access static array from another java class?

If you have any worked through examples, that would be a real help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ArrayAdapter.createFromResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#createFromResource%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) has the arguments of

- `context` The application's environment.
- `textArrayResId` The identifier of the array to use as the data
  source.
- `textViewResId` The identifier of the layout used to create views.

Then how can we pass more parameters.

I think you want to create ArrayAdapter using this constructor

[`ArrayAdapter(Context, int, int, T[])`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29)

and make sure your parameters sequence is also correct as the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not part of the example, it seems like `this` is not the activity / context, but you have some internal class. It should be something like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( 
TheActivityName.this, mArrayList, R.layout.sq,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
//^ Your activity name, to make it clear to the compiler that you want "this" object of the activity
```

Answer (score 1):

createFromResource is expecting the array resource id from the values.xml file.

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="mArrayList">
        <item>title</item>
        <item>sex</item>
        <item>name</item>
        <item>fff</item>
        <item>eee</item>
        <item>iii</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And you pass the resource id which is R.array.mArrayList

```
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.mArrayList,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```